# Get elements for each instance of a ClassName

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

The following code pulls pysicochemical properties from the following link into excel:

https://echa.europa.eu/brief-profile/-/briefprofile/100.002.098

```
   Public Sub GetContents()
    
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    XMLReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/brief-profile/-/briefprofile/100.002.098", False
    XMLReq.send
     
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

    Set SubSectList = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("col-xs-12 col-lg-10 MainContent")(1)
    Set SubSects = SubSectList.getElementsByTagName("dt")
   
    For Each SubSect In SubSects

    Debug.Print SubSect.innerText & " : " & SubSect.NextSibling.innerText

    Next SubSect

End Sub
```

I've noticed however that I am getting duplicate results. Inspecting the page I can see that this occurs because the results contain both `study results` and `summaries` where summaries contain a duplicate of the most important reuslt.

Now looking at the code, I realise that im gathering all elements from `("col-xs-12 col-lg-10 MainContent")(1)` and pulling the elements (header) with tag `dt` and the next sibling (data).

I wish to modify the code to pull data from just the study data. Looking at the page code, each study data has ClassName `EndpointContent` and this leads to a general coding question using all of this as an example.

How can I write code to loop through elements with ClassName `EndpointContent`, return the data within this section, and then move onto the Next `EndpointContent` and repeat.

My attempt to achieve this is below but I just dont know how to tie in the SubSects into the SubSectList when elements are are collection (i.e. not specified with (1)) and I get the runtime error 438 object doesn't support property or method:

```
Public Sub GetContents()
    
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    XMLReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/brief-profile/-/briefprofile/100.002.098", False
    XMLReq.send
     
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

    Set SubSectList = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("EndpointContent")
    
    Set SubSects = SubSectList.getElementsByTagName("dt")
    
    
    For Each SubSect In SubSectList

    Debug.Print SubSect.innerText & " : " & SubSect.NextSibling.innerText

    Next SubSect

End Sub
```

Ideally I would like to keep the code as original as possible please.

Comment: Nick  - do you mind telling me what version of Office you are running? Also, what is the file version of your mshtml.dll? If you go VBE > Tools > References and select Microsoft HTML Object Library then click Browser on the right hand side menu, it should open a folder in Windows > System 32. If you look for the mshtml.dll > right click on it > properties > details > there should then be a file version number e.g. 11.0.19041.985?

Comment: @QHarr Hi, Apologies in the delay responding I was away this weekend. So I'm working on a company PC with Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise Version 2008 (Build 13127.21064). Unfortunately Its up to the company to update this. As for the File version of mshtml.dll its 11.00.18362.1156. Hope this explains some of the inconsistencies we've had with code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want it like your existing code then gather the list of `Endpointcontent` class elements and outer loop those, then inner loop for the `dt` elements of each outer node. Then, depending on your Office version, you actually need a chained `nextSibling` with the later Office updates (older ones just used `nextSibling`):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetContents()
    
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    XMLReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/brief-profile/-/briefprofile/100.002.098", False
    XMLReq.send
     
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

    Dim SubSectList As Object, SubSect As Object
    
    Set SubSectList = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("EndpointContent")
    
    Dim dt As Object
    
    r = 1
    
    For Each SubSect In SubSectList
    
        For Each dt In SubSect.getElementsByTagName("dt")
            
            ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1) = dt.innerText & " : " & dt.NextSibling.NextSibling.innerText
            'ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1) = dt.innerText & " : " & dt.NextSibling.innerText
            r = r + 1
            
        Next
    
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi again thank you. Theres something odd about `dt.NextSibling.NextSibling.innerText`. Just as before with that error on the shared workbook, the first 2 results are printed and then I get the runtime error 91. watching it its almost as if its trying to pull the data too quickly.  Is there anyway to slow this step down?

Comment: The response is the response. I get the full set back. I am not sure why you have this issue. What is your office version? I have seen html rendered differently according to office version where it ends up being just nextSibling and not chained. Something to do with handling of text nodes and whitespace I think.

Comment: Hi @QHarr, `dt.NextSibling.innerText` worked for me instead of `dt.NextSibling.NextSibling.innerText`. It's again because of the variation of office version.

Comment: @SIM Ah that works for me now! Thanks again to both of you